# Rewrite htaccess rule for all posts

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a rule for a migration from a php custom CMS to Wordpress.

Actually, the standard url for posts is:

**www.domain.com/category_with_underscores/YYYYMMDD/12345/title_of_the_post_with_underscores/**

Note: 12345 is the ID of the post in the old custom db.

I'd love to obtain a rewrite URL with 301 like this:

**www.domain.com/category-with-dashes/title-of-the-post-with-dashes/**

but I'm having some difficulties with regex.

Can someone help me?
Is it a good idea to remove some part of the url (like the ID because I cannot replicate it in WP) and / or the date or is not?

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: would it be acceptable to do it within the child theme functions.php before load of the page?  that would give you ultimate control and flexibility moreso than the terse htaccess language constructs.

Comment: thanks, but about the seo is the same or the htaccess solution is to be preferred?

Comment: no, in both cases you are able to send headers before the server sends any other output.  in fact, i'll post a nice wordpress plugin that i saw when looking at this for you.  perhaps that will be a good solution for you since it includes tracking on "hits" to those urls (although it may not support the customized regex you require).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the OP indicates in comments that htaccess is but one solution to get to the end SEO goal, I recommend https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ as a solution.  If it does not have the required regex customization necessary, I will expand my answer with a version that will ultimately do what the htaccess would but in less terse syntax and within Wordpress itself.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try it immediately and I'll let you know ;) Thanks